# Makefile $(eval ...) : what's the behavior when plutiple jobs run simultaneously?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, jobs

I've defined the following rule:

```
$(OUTDIR)/%_sorted.bam:
    $(eval SAMPLE:=$(subst _sorted,,$(notdir $(basename $@))))
    (...) do something with $(SAMPLE)
```

can I use it safely (= is it a "local variable" to the rule ?) with

```
make -j (number of jobs)
```

or does the variable $(SAMPLE) will be replaced for each (simultaneous) invocation of the rule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. GNU make expands the whole recipe prior to executing it. Job server mode only affects the execution of sub-processes spawned by make, everything else is single threaded.